# Flowing transactions into gRpc

Tags: c#, wcf, transactions, grpc, transactionscope

I recently converted a WCF service to gRpc. The WCF service was able to flow transactions from client side into the service. All it needed was to place the WCF call inside a using TransactionScope. If there was a failure anywhere the transaction rolled back. Wondering if it is even possible to flow a transaction into gRpc. If not how might one approach this sort of challenge?

Comment: About converting WCF project to gRPC project you can refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/introduction

Comment: Unfortunately the Microsoft documentation does not cover transactions.

Comment: There is no transaction support in the implementation of gRPC, gRPC aims to become a general RPC framework, and transaction is a very specific concept.

Comment: I am aware gRpc does not have Windows transaction support. But seeing that WCF has this capability, I am asking how it can be done. How does one build a client that participates with MSDTC? It may be complex and not worth the effort but that is not the question here. The question is how?